# pandas.concat() second argument?

Tags: python, pandas

I freshly installed a program through pip3 and it now fails like this:

```
pandas.concat(dataFrameList, 0)
TypeError: concat() takes 1 positional argument, but 2 were given
```

I looked at the `concat()` function prototype in Pandas 0.9, 1.x and 2.x documentation but it appears that this second argument was never allowed; it works with Pandas 1.5 though...

**What is the `0` supposed to do? Is it safe to remove it from the code?**

Comment: Safe as in "probably won't burn down your house", yes, but it's likely the program has other bugs too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is shorcut to `axis` parameter:

```
pandas.concat(dataFrameList, axis=0)
```

what is default parameter, so should be removed:

```
pandas.concat(dataFrameList)
```

Comment: It was the axis indeed: the calculations completed successfully and the results seem fine.